# xcode archive error after flutter app version change

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

I have completed the release of the flatter app version with 1.0.0+1 and uploaded it to the app store connection
After releasing it like that, we found a bug, fixed the bug, and then the version
Changed to 1.0.1+2
I don't know if this is the right way to change the version, but everyone said that

pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.1+2
```

local.properties

```
flutter.versionName=1.0.1
flutter.versionCode=2
```

app/build.gradle

```
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0.1'
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '2'
}
```

I changed all the versions to 1.0.1+2 and after running the Runner.xcworkspace file, I changed the version of Runner/General/identity
be as shown in the picture below

[image: Runner.xcworkspace image]

After that, I changed the Build Configuration to Release and ran Archive, but I got the following error

[image: Archive error]

I only changed the plutter app version and I don't understand why such an error suddenly occurred.

And I deleted the file as instructed by the stack overflow with commands such as flutter clean / flutter pub get etc I tried to recreate them, but they all failed
I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help me

Comment: You should only have needed to change the version of your app in your pubspec.yaml file.  The other items you changed look to be related to the version of flutter you are using, not the version of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Change version to : 1.0.1+1 in pubspec.yaml

1.0.1 is the version number and +1 means the build number

then

```
run flutter build iOS
```

after that open runner in Xcode and create archive then only the version name and build number change.